# How send object in datatables function with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datatables

i have this code :

```
    vm.dtColumns = [
     DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('').withTitle('Tipo').renderWith(function(input) {
                return input = '<input class="form-control input-xs" type="text" style="max-width: 60px"/>'
            }).notSortable(),

            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Grupo').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                // console.log(angular.element('grupo-' + data.pos).val());
                return data = '<input id="grupo-' + data.pos + '" ng-model="this.grupo_' + data.pos + '" class="form-control input-xs" type="text" style="max-width: 40px"/>'
            }).notSortable(),

            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('oferta').withTitle('Oferta').renderWith( function(data) {
                return data = '$ <input id="oferta-' + data.pos + '" class="form-control input-xs" type="text" style="max-width: 80px" value="'+ data +'"/>' 
            }).notSortable(),

            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Link').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                return data = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button" ng-click="vm.generateLink(\'' + data.influencer.id + '\' , \'' + data.influencer.username + '\' , ' + data.ppr + ')" href=""><i ng-hide="vm.creatingLink" class="fas fa-link"></i> <i ng-show="vm.creatingLink" class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i></a>';
            }).notSortable(),       

        ];
```

this is the photo:

[image]

now i have a problem with the data, i need send the data of the person selected to the function when i click the icon link

i try send the object data but datable it cant,

this is the buttom:

```
ng-click="vm.generateLink(\'' + data.influencer.id + '\' , \'' + data.influencer.username + '\' , ' + data.ppr + ')"
```

i send the data 1 for 1, but i dont know how send the data of the input (Tipo, grupo, oferta) to the `generateLink() function`

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `vm.` in html template. directly call `generateLink()`.

```
 ng-click="generateLink(\'' + data.influencer.id + '\' , \'' + data.influencer.username + '\' , ' + data.ppr + ')"
```

Comment: and any idea how can send the data of input? this is a array  :/

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: for example with ng-repeat i can send the data to the function with ng-model, for example: ng-model="user.type", ng-model="user.group", ng-model="user.offer" and in the bottom ng-click="generateLink(user)" and here i with this code when i write in any input, write in all input because all has the same name

Comment: `ng-click="generateLink(user)" ` is this not working then ?